# Implementing Addition Using Bit Operations

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, binary-operations

I have a system in which calculations are performed on integers. The following bit operations are defined in it: AND, OR, NOT, XOR. I want to define the addition operation in it, which would be expressed through the bit operations available to me.
Various algorithms were found in which a bit shift is involved. But how can I implement it using the given functions?
Is there an addition algorithm that only works with the specified bit operations?

Comment: Your operations are logically complete (with more that a little overlap), so you can replace any other operators with combinators of your operators if necessary.

Comment: Can you suggest a method with which I can achieve this?

Comment: Bit shifts are required because of the need to hadle carry from one bit position to a more significant position. That is how addition works.

Comment: See here: https://www.elprocus.com/half-adder-and-full-adder/